# How to present a popup viewController using ionic (v1) framework?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am implementing an application using **[ionic v1](https://ionicframework.com/)**, im creating a utility `.js` file to separate some functions that will be used only on development environment. I`m trying to implement a function that can be accessed from any **ionic view**. The code that im using is:

```
myApp.prototype.showAlert = function() {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Gendalf',
     template: 'You shall not Pass'
   });
 };
```

[**Example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBrXS.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ionic docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)

```
   // An alert dialog
   $scope.showAlert = function() {
      var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Don\'t eat that!',
        template: 'It might taste good'
      });

      alertPopup.then(function(res) {
      console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
     });
  };
```

Then when you want to show it just call the method:

```
$scope.showAlert();
```

In your example code you would call it like:

```
 myApp.showAlert();
```